# Phone responds to swipe but not touch - hardware or software problem?

Tags: iphone

My phone responds to swiping in a certain area, but not to touch. Can this be a problem with the touchscreen, or is it a software problem?

Have tried wiping the phone and reinstalling to no help.

Comment: If you've tried wiping the phone and reinstalling, it might be more of a hardware issue than a software issue _(unless you have access to a different phone with the same software version that responds in the same way...)_

Comment: I think going in to an Apple Store, if you can, is a good idea. Good things could happen!

Answer (score 1):

### In order to fix this problem follow these steps.

1) Plug your **iPhone** into your computer and open **Itunes**.
2) Select **iCloud Backup** or **Backup without iCloud.**
3) After a successful backup click **Restore my iPhone.**
4) Attempt using your fresh iPhone and on the phone select restore from **iCloud.**

### If this Does not work follow these steps.

1) Call or go online to schedule a genius bar appointment.
2) Pay and have apple replace your screen or recalibrate it.
3) Use craigslist or something to get a aftermarket screen or calibration.